# We don't need to [retrieve] anything

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retrieve) tag is one of the most vague tags I have ever seen. It has only three followers and 491 questions, and doesn't have any wiki. Is there any reason we need this tag?

Comment: Yup. It's as meta as `[get]`, and does not share the chance of being an HTTP request method.

Comment: But, but, I always retrieve my knowledge here!

Comment: At least it has experts, unfortunately they are all dogs :)

Comment: No, it's not meta.  (example meta tags are "homework" or "beginner").  It comes from typing complete sentences in the tags list.  BURN IT!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET this is the internet. It doesn't matter that they're dogs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Done.

[image: Burned]

Please [care for the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged).

Comment: There; widows and orphans taken care of.

Answer (score 4):

What are you retrieving? How can anyone be an expert in retrieving?

Let it burn.